# Uniformly continuous unitary representations.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, representation-theory

Let $U$ be a unitary rep. of $\mathbb{R}^d$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$, and $H\cong\oplus L^2_{\mu_v}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the spectral decomposition (according to the spectral theorem for these representations). Then it seems that $t\mapsto U(t)$ is continuous (in the operator norm) iff there is a bounded set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the suppport of all the spectral measures $\mu_v$ is contained in $K$. Is this true, and how could one prove it?
I would be happy if someone gives me a sketch of proof and hints, containing the main idea.

Comment: Remark: In the notation of the bounty $U=\pi$.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1029000269

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Nope, but I think a much more elementary solution is possible than this one. it is not supposed to be that difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I must be missing something - this seems trivial. The argument below maybe takes more than one line, but there's nothing clever about it, every single step is an "ok, just work it out" thing.

Say $K_n$ is the support of $\mu_n$. Then $$||U_x-I||=\sup_n\sup_{t\in K_n}
|e^{ix\cdot t}-1|.$$ So for $\delta>0$ we have $$\sup_{|x|<\delta}||U_x-I||=\sup_n\sup_{t\in K_n}
\sup_{|x|<\delta}|e^{ix\cdot t}-1|.$$

**Lemma** Suppose $\delta>0$ and $t\in\Bbb R^d$.

1. $\sup_{|x|<\delta}|e^{it\cdot x}-1|\le\delta|t|$.
2. If $\delta|t|>\pi$ then $\sup_{|x|<\delta}|e^{it\cdot x}-1|=2$.

**Lemma** Suppose $\delta>0$ and $K\subset \Bbb R^d$. Let $r=\sup_{t\in K}|t|$.

1. $\sup_{t\in K}\sup_{|x|<\delta}|e^{it\cdot x}-1|\le\delta r$.
2. If $\delta r>\pi$ then $\sup_{t\in K}\sup_{|x|<\delta}|e^{it\cdot x}-1|=2$.

Now let $r_n=\sup_{t\in K_n}|t|$.

Suppose $r_n$ is unbounded. Then for every $\delta>0$ there exists $n$ so $r_n\delta>\pi$, hence $$\sup_{|x|<\delta}||U_x-I||=2\quad(\delta>0)$$and so our representation is not continuous in norm.

Suppose on the other hand that $r_n\le r$ for all $n$. Then $$\sup_{|x|<\delta}||U_x-I||\le r\delta,$$and so we do have continuity in norm.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think this should work out. but could you tell me precisely why the first equation is true? thanks

Comment: @BenDover Follows from two things - I don't know which is the one you want me to explain: (i) If $T$ is a bounded operator on $H$, $H$ is the orthogonal direct sum of subspaces $H_j$, and each $H_j$ is invariant under $T$, then the norm of $T$ is the sup of the norms of the "restrictions" $T_j:H_j\to H_j$. (ii) If $\mu$ is a sigma-finite measure, $m\in L^\infty(\mu)$, and $T:L^2\to L^2$ is defined by $Tf=mf$ (ie $T$ is multiplication by $m$) then $||T||=||m||_\infty$.

Comment: @BenDover Oh. And also of course (0) if $\psi$ is as in the statement of the spectral theorem that you quoted then $||\psi^{-1}T\psi||=||T||$. (Or the other way around, depending on which side of the diagram $T$ is on...)